# Connect svg rect with an accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, accordion

I have a svg image with a mouse hover on four rect elements and an accordion with four buttons done with javascript. I want to connect each element by hovering them simultaneously (a rect and button accordion) and by clicking on a svg rect it will open a button accordion and by clicking on an accordion it will fill a rect. You can check my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pfrutuoso/zcsj8g05/2/
This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="stage_info">
            <button class="accordion">Stage 1</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Information here..</p>
            </div>

            <button class="accordion">Stage 2</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Information here..</p>
            </div>
            <button class="accordion">Stage 3</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Information here..</p>
            </div>
            <button class="accordion">Stage 4</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <p>Information here..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stage_img">
            <map id="big_stage">
            <svg version="1.1" id="stadium" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
            width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 456.122 451.02" enable-background="new 0 0 456.122 451.02"
            xml:space="preserve">
       <rect id="stage4" x="25.51" y="25.51" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
       <rect id="stage3" x="230.612" y="25.51" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
       <rect id="stage2" x="25.51" y="229.592" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
       <rect id="stage1" x="230.612" y="229.592" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
       </svg>
           </map>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My css:

```
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.stage_info,
.stage_img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 80px);
    vertical-align: top;
}

rect {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}

rect:hover {
    fill: #ccc;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

And my javascript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do it as procedurally as possible as that seemed to be what you were going for in your JS.
I added value attributes to your stage buttons with the `id` of the corresponding `rect` elements, and I added a `class` called `grey` with the same properties as those applied when hovering.

```js
 let stgInf = document.querySelector(".stage_info");
 let svg = document.querySelector("#stadium");

 function onClick(num) {
  let acc = stgInf.querySelector(`.accordion:nth-of-type(${num})`);
  let panel = acc.nextElementSibling;
  let rect = svg.querySelector(`rect#${acc.getAttribute("value")}`);
  return () => {
   acc.classList.toggle("active");
   if (acc.classList.contains("active")) {
    panel.style.display = "block";
    rect.classList.add("grey");
   } else {
    panel.style.display = "none";
    rect.classList.remove("grey");
   }
  }
 }

 function hover(num) {
  let acc = stgInf.querySelector(`.accordion:nth-of-type(${num})`);
  let rect = svg.querySelector(`rect#${acc.getAttribute("value")}`);
  return (event) => {
   if (event.type === "mouseenter") {
    acc.classList.add("grey");
    rect.classList.add("grey");
   } else if (!acc.classList.contains("active")) {
    acc.classList.remove("grey");
    rect.classList.remove("grey");
   }
  }
 }

 let accs = stgInf.querySelectorAll(".accordion");
 let i = 1;
 for (let acc of accs) {
  let rect = svg.querySelector(`rect#${acc.getAttribute("value")}`);
  acc.addEventListener("click", onClick(i));
  acc.addEventListener("mouseenter", hover(i));
  acc.addEventListener("mouseout", hover(i));
  rect.addEventListener("click", onClick(i));
  rect.addEventListener("mouseenter", hover(i));
  rect.addEventListener("mouseout", hover(i));
  ++i;
 }
```

```css
  .accordion {
   background-color: #eee;
   color: #444;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 18px;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .panel {
   padding: 0 18px;
   background-color: white;
   display: none;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

  .wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 1140px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .stage_info,
  .stage_img {
   display: inline-block;
   width: calc(50% - 80px);
   vertical-align: top;
  }

  rect {
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 999;
   position: relative;
  }

  .grey,
  .active,
  .accordion:hover,
  rect:hover {
   fill: #ccc;
   background-color: #ccc;
   pointer-events: all;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stage_info">
    <button class="accordion" value="stage1">Stage 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Information here..</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion" value="stage2">Stage 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Information here..</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion" value="stage3">Stage 3</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Information here..</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion" value="stage4">Stage 4</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Information here..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stage_img">
    <map id="big_stage">
            <svg version="1.1" id="stadium" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
            width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 456.122 451.02" enable-background="new 0 0 456.122 451.02"
            xml:space="preserve">
    <rect id="stage4" x="25.51" y="25.51" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
    <rect id="stage3" x="230.612" y="25.51" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
    <rect id="stage2" x="25.51" y="229.592" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
    <rect id="stage1" x="230.612" y="229.592" fill="#1C6131" width="200" height="200"/>
   </svg>
           </map>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I implemented the hover functionality you mentioned in your comment by adding mouseenter and mouseout event listeners in addition to the click listeners.

Comment: my english wasn´t good enough. Your answer and your code was on point. The part that is missing and you didn't understood (my fault) is this: how can I put the hover effect (for example, the background-color #ccc) at the same time in two different elements: a button accordion and a svg rect. Hope you understand now.

Comment: So to be clear, when one of the buttons is hovered you want the corresponding rect to appear as if it is hovered and vice versa in addition to the clicking functionality?

Comment: Yep, that's the objective. I'm trying to do that with your code but my javascript it's still basic.

Comment: If my answer is correct could you accept it please?
Checkmark under the upvote/downvote arrows. Ty.